# How can I add volume slider to Android action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add volume to action bar. When user clicks on that action it should place slider inside action bar for selecting right volume.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to handle this is to use `ActionBar.setCustomView`.

Here's an example that controls the media volume:

First, you'll need to create the custom layout that contains your `SeekBar`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now implement `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`and declare a couple of variables:

```
/** Used to actually adjust the volume */
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
/** Used to control the volume for a given stream type */
private SeekBar mVolumeControls;
/** True is the volume controls are showing, false otherwise */
private boolean mShowingControls;
```

In `onCreate` or wherever you choose to, inflate and apply the custom `View` to the `ActionBar`.

```
    // Control the media volume
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Initialize the AudioManager
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // Inflate the custom ActionBar View
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_action_bar_slider, null);
    mVolumeControls = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
    // Set the max range of the SeekBar to the max volume stream type
    mVolumeControls.setMax(mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
    // Bind the OnSeekBarChangeListener
    mVolumeControls.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    // Apply the custom View to the ActionBar
    getActionBar().setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
```

To toggle the controls when your `MenuItem` is pressed, call `ActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled` and don't forget to update the `SeekBar` progress to the current volume level you're controlling.

```
        // Toggle the custom View's visibility
        mShowingControls = !mShowingControls;
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(mShowingControls);
        // Set the progress to the current volume level of the stream
        mVolumeControls.setProgress(mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
```

To control the volume stream, in `OnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged` call `AudioManager.setStreamVolume`

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // Adjust the volume for the given stream type
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
}
```

And finally in `OnSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch`, remove the custom controls to display the `ActionBar` normally again.

```
    // Remove the SeekBar from the ActionBar
    mShowingControls = false;
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
```

Here's a picture of before and after you press the `MenuItem`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503350/1364896) of a similar question. He wanted to add Full audio Control buttons. You will find how to add the control `Seekbar` into your `actionBar` and how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

first, add the seek bar to the toolbar as you want, this is my solution

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="Interval timer">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/AudioSliderToolbar"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:progress="999"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Second

create two variables

```
private var volumeSeekbar: SeekBar? = null
private var audioManager: AudioManager? = null
```

Third

In on create

```
    //audio seekbar
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    initControls()
```

method initControls()

```
//audio seek bar
private fun initControls() {
    try {
        volumeSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.AudioSliderToolbar)
        audioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        volumeSeekbar!!.setMax(
            audioManager!!
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        )
        volumeSeekbar!!.setProgress(
            audioManager!!
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        )
        volumeSeekbar!!.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, i: Int, b: Boolean) {
                // Display the current progress of SeekBar
                audioManager!!.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    i, 0
                );
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                // Do something
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "start tracking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                // Do something
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "stop tracking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //e.toString();
    }


}
```