# How to set expanded ActionView's width in SupportActionBar to fill the available space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I try to set up a MenuItem with an `actionView` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html).

In my case the `ActionView` Widget is a [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html).

The problem is, that when the `ActionView` is shown on icon click, its width is way smaller than expected as you can see in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

The docs say:

> If the widget is on the app bar, the app should display the widget as
>   an icon. If the widget is in the overflow menu, the app should display
>   the widget as a menu item. **When the user interacts with the action
>   view, it expands to fill the app bar**.

In my case, nothing gets "expanded". Instead of taking up the whole width of the `ActionBar`, its tiny.

To fix it I tried using another View like an `EditText`, but got similar Results. (The EditText is small on start, but expands on writing in it).
It seems to work with a `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` as used in the docs.

I also tried it with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` providing a Toolbar in the layout without any noticeable difference.

Here is the code I used:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* set this on other layout with toolbar in it
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.camera_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

app_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item"
        android:title="Action"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_in_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SeekBar"
        />
</menu>
```

I also tried `app:actionViewLayout=@layout/seekbar_layout` instead of `actionViewClass` 
where seekbarLayout was something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<SeekBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Where I also tried different versions of `ViewGroups` around it like Linear, Relative or FrameLayouts, or tried to set a fixed width of my SeekBar without any success.

What Am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want a seekBar as menu item . then you should add it as a view inside toolbar. MenuItems are of specific size .

Comment: could you be a bit more verbose? How do you mean "add it inside toolbar"? Does that mean I have to take care of showing/hiding the SeekBar myself and cannot use build in-mechanics of ActionBar/actionView? why does this work for `support.SearchView` in the docs

Comment: `SearchView` is also a menu item . I think when it expand then other view is visible i.e the search edit text.

Comment: `SearchView` extends `LinearLayout` and says something about beeing `iconified` by default in the docs.... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html I guess thats the property i Kinda need

Comment: can you provide a GitHub repository of you code.

Comment: @Ashwanikumar no, sorry. But above code is all you need. Empty Activity, addOptionsMenuItem with some kind of actionView/actionLayout which is no `SearchView`

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22104694/321106)

Comment: @artkoenig No, not really. The question there is how to bring a Seekbar inside the ActionBar. My question is explicitly about the menu `ActionView` feature, which doesn't seem to work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "magic" takes place in `Toolbar.expandItemActionView`. This method overrides the layout parameters of the expanded `ActionView` and sets the width to `wrap_content`. Now to one possible solution:

`Toolbar.expandItemActionView` checks if the `ActionView` implements `CollapsibleActionView` interface and calls `CollapsibleActionView.onActionViewExpanded` method if this is the case. This is your chance to fix the layout paramters and set the width to `match_parent`. Derive a custom class from the `SeekBar` and let it implement `CollapsibleActionView`:

```
public class CollapsibleSeekBar extends AppCompatSeekBar implements CollapsibleActionView {
    public CollapsibleSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CollapsibleSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CollapsibleSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionViewExpanded() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        setLayoutParams(params);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionViewCollapsed() {

    }
}
```

Use it in your menu item via `app:actionViewClass`.

Also make sure to use the appropriate `CollapsibleActionView`.

If you are using `android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar` you also need `android.support.v7.view.CollapsibleActionView`.

If you have an `android.widget.Toolbar` use  `android.view.CollapsibleActionView`

Comment: sorry, I tried but `onActionViewExpanded` will never get called! Thus, I get the same Results

Comment: Do you know a possible reasoning for overriding the LayoutParams of ActionViews? Does that prevent something else?

Comment: The reason is, that an ActionView inserted by a menu entry has no parent view (getParent() = null). [Here is the the corresponding code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/lollipop-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.java#1944).

Comment: I see, but shouldn't `generateDefaultLayoutParams()` return height=`WRAP_CONTENT` and width=`MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` twice?

Comment: The reason for that can definitely be explained by a Google engineer :)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Adding Seekbar as the menu item, will take up the size of default `menu item`. 
If you need `Seekbar` to extend across the `appbar`, then you can create your own `Toolbar` and add `SeekBar` like this.

```
<youtLayoutRoot>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="10"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<!-- your content layout here -->
</youtLayoutRoot>
```

Make the theme of your `activity` as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and run the `application`. You should be able to see the `seekbar` spanning across the `toolbar`.

In your activity just inflate the menu and it will take ut its size.
It works for me and hope that seekbar with menu item will also work for you.

[image]

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_delete)
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.vector_back)
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.delete -> {
                deleteCall()
                true
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: shure, I have a Seekbar inside my toolbar, but If I add items via `onCreateOptionsMenu` it doesn't show up, cause the seekbar is taking up all space. I wanted the seekbar as `actionView` show up on a MenuItem click

Comment: what you are saying is also possible. I'll try it and will update the code.

Comment: @RafaelT hey is this what you are asking?

Comment: no, not really. 1. I explicitly asked for `actionView` as stated in the docs I linked on top of my question. 2. Code you provided seems copied somewhere else, doesn't solve the problem and is not even java (kotlin?)

Comment: *In this release, Android introduces a new Toolbar widget. This is a generalization of the Action Bar pattern that gives you much more control and flexibility. Toolbar is a view in your hierarchy just like any other, making it easier to interleave with the rest of your views, animate it, and react to scroll events. You can also set it as your Activity’s action bar, meaning that your standard options menu actions will be displayed on it.*

Comment: Yes, my code I in kotlin. And I have used the toolbar to get much freedom. Plus the code which I have provided is written by me and not copied :( . If you think its copied please show me from where. I would be very happy that my code is used at many places. ; )

Comment: and you can do setSupportActionBar(toolbar) and boom, your actionBar is here.

Comment: sorry, I did't mean to be offensive with copycode. But still, my question wasn't about using a Toolbar/ActionBar, but about how a `actionView` is supposed to work on "normal Views".  The passage I meant in the link was this: *If the widget is on the app bar, the app should display the widget as an icon. If the widget is in the overflow menu, the app should display the widget as a menu item. **When the user interacts with the action view, it expands to fill the app bar.*** with regards to my emphasis. In my case No view "expands to fill"